# Количество подключений

Tags: sql-server, сервер

Есть сервер Widows Server 2008 r2 и есть приложения, обращающиеся к серверу, по XML и SOAP портам. Подключений к портам XML, я так понял, всего 62?

1.Как называются эти подключения правильно, чтобы их поискать в инете?

2.Можно ли увеличить количество подключений?

Comment: клиенты напрямую работают с sql server? можно сделать web-сервис который будет обрабатывать запросы. и при необходимости обращаться к базе данных.

Comment: вопрос есть ли ограничения на самом SQL Server на подключения.
на серваке сервисы обрабатывающие поступающие из вне данные  (датчики и т.п ) и записывают в бд. Пользователь пользуется интерфесом и для получения инфы коннектится на сервер.

Comment: нет никаких ограничений, если вы сами их не установили

Comment: ограничение может быть в ОС, см. ["Значение MaxUserPort слишком мало"](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa995661(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Можно подробнее про эти ограничения ОС

Comment: Называются они _endpoints_. Вроде бы нет ограничений на количество подключений к endpoint, но могу ошибаться. По крайней мере проверьте разрешенное число подключений к самому SqlServer: `select value, value_in_use from sys.configurations where name = 'user connections'`. Если нет ограничений, то должно быть по нолям.